# Why magento is redirecting secure url to unsecure url

Tags: adminhtml

I've been using Magento shop on an unsecured host for almost a month. I recently setup a secure host(SSL) and directed it to point to same directory as used for unsecured host. But to my surprise, when i try to login to admin panel using secure url, it redirects me to the unsecured one.

I have changed `secure_base_url` in core_... table, as well as cleared the caches, but its still not working.

Whats happenning ?

Thanks in advance for the help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at "System > Configuration > Web > Secure > Use Secure URLs in Admin"
I believe the default is "No".

Comment: Wow...its working....thnk u sooo much :-)